# check with javascript if textbox is empty while using ajaxcontroltoolkit TextBoxWatermark

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watermark

I have an asp.net TextBox and I'm using the [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)  of AjaxControlToolkit to have it display some hing text while the box is empty.

Problem is, onclient click of a certain button, I want to determine if the textbox is empty. The javascript code of

> document.getElementById(fieldName).value == ""

Is not working, since the WaterMark extender with it's hint text making the code to think the field is not empty.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrapper to access whether the watermark is being displayed or not with `get_IsWaterMarked`.

```
Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWrapper.get_Wrapper(document.getElementById(fieldName)).get_IsWatermarked()
```

I tried this with version 4.1.7.1213 of AjaxControlToolKit.

Got the code from looking at the source code of the TextBoxWatermark control.
Refer to this: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/TextboxWatermark/TextboxWatermark.pre.js